# Building Webkit in Android

Tags: android, webkit, android-ndk

Earlier i tried to build webkit for Android in Windows using Android NDK. Then i learned that it could not be built in NDK,It could be built only in platform build system. Then  I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and downloaded and compiled android source code successfully. But Now, I am not getting any way to go for the next step. How to build webkit ,or how to use the compiled codes.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Do you want to link custom webkit implementation to your Android app? Or you are trying to build Android webkit implementation for non-Android usage?

Answer (score 3):

Building Android source code will build WebKit too. WebKit source resides at external/webkit folder and gets built as libwebcore.so (out/target/product//symbols/system/lib/libwebcore.so).